# Javascript conflict with Foundation

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have Foundation installed in an application where prettyPhoto is also used.

The problem is the top-bar menu is disabled (hovering, links and dropdown are all disabled [as per this page here](http://acharm.iwant2go2.com/catalog_categoris/1) on certain pages, whereas on any other page [for example here](http://acharm.iwant2go2.com/) the functions are fully enabled.

I have isolated the problem in the following generated code:

```
<a href="/uploads/catalog/image/8/3210.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[]" title="3210F - Women&#x27;s-T 80/20"><img alt="Base_3210" src="/uploads/catalog/image/8/base_3210.jpg" /></a>
```

If it is removed, the functions return.  I believe it is a javascript issue because links and css would appear to not cause the issue in other page locations...

How can both set of functions be made to co-exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with JavaScript conflicts.
It is because of the

```
<div id="container">
```

according to css

```
#container { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 142px; 
  z-index: 300;
}
```

your z-index is 300. Which means it is on top of everything including couple of menu-options.
remove your z-index property everything should be fine

Comment: That was it.  Was not expecting that result given the top padding; expecting it to pass unscathed.  I actually had background images I needed to get beneath  the container, so I did toggle the z-indicies a bit.  the container css is now beneath the header css, but above the footer css.  Z-indicies can remain but they have to be layered properly.  Good lesson learned.  Thanx!